# Simple SQL query getting "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined"?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm just trying to get the sum of money from a column.

```
SELECT SUM(amount_usd)
FROM WIRE_MSTR, TRANS_MSTR
INNER JOIN WIRE_MSTR ON WIRE_MSTR.trans_id = TRANS_MSTR.trans_id
WHERE WIRE_MSTR.dest_cntry = 'CANADA' AND TRANS_MSTR.trans_yyyymm = '201510';
```

But on line 4 I get an error "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined."
I've referenced everything, what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you include the SQL statements for defining your tables?

Comment: Oracle errors come from Oracle, not MySQL.

Comment: When several tables are involved, qualify all columns! (E.g. `SUM(tablename.amount_usd)`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using implicit and explicit join syntax. You should remove the implicit syntax:

```
SELECT SUM(amount_usd)
FROM TRANS_MSTR
INNER JOIN WIRE_MSTR ON WIRE_MSTR.trans_id = TRANS_MSTR.trans_id
WHERE WIRE_MSTR.dest_cntry = 'CANADA' AND TRANS_MSTR.trans_yyyymm = '201510';
```

The problem was, you had `WIRE_MSTR` twice in your FROM clause.

Comment: Yet another Oracle problem solved by using proper syntax. Those comma joins are like a plague.

Comment: @JacobH Indeed, every time I am surprised when sql students post queries with these joins. Do these still get taught?

Comment: Yes, they still get taught. If you also go to reddit's "sql" sub forum there are frequently posts like "My teacher gave us this query..." using comma joins. It's *very much* still taught incorrectly in school. I've even seen people claiming that they are *faster* than the explicit syntax, with no data to back it up of course.

Comment: @Jacob & Honey: there are still Oracle tools (such as Reports Developer 10g, not to mention older ones) which don't accept ANSI joins and you just *have to* use the old syntax. Not that Reports say "ups! What's that?"  for ANSI join - nope, it crashes & disappears from the screen as if it was disintegrated. So ...

Comment: Sounds like Oracle is outdated and antiquated from what you are describing. Maybe they should try to change that? There's no good excuse for being 26 years outdated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. You got WIRE_MSTR twice.

```
SELECT SUM(amount_usd)
FROM TRANS_MSTR
INNER JOIN WIRE_MSTR ON WIRE_MSTR.trans_id = TRANS_MSTR.trans_id
WHERE WIRE_MSTR.dest_cntry = 'CANADA' AND TRANS_MSTR.trans_yyyymm = '201510';
```

Comment: Umpf... Too late